# R: Combine rows in same data.frame

Tags: r, matrix, row

I have a simple R problem, but I just can't find the answer.
I have a dataframe like this:

```
A    1    0    0    0    0    0
B    0    1    0    0    0    0
B    0    0    1    0    0    1
B    0    0    0    0    1    0
C    1    0    0    0    0    0
C    0    0    0    1    1    0
```

And i want it to be just like this:

```
A    1    0    0    0    0    0
B    0    1    1    0    1    1
C    1    0    0    1    1    0
```

Thank you very much!

Regards Lisanne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possbility using `tapply`:

```
cbind(unique(dat[1]), do.call(rbind, tapply(dat[-1], dat[[1]], colSums)))

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
# 1  A  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 2  B  0  1  1  0  1  1
# 5  C  1  0  0  1  1  0
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 4):

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
    V3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), V5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), V6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L), V7 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

You could...

```
aggregate(.~ V1 , data =dat, sum)
```

or

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(V1), function(x) colSums(x[,2:7])  )
```

If you're working with a `data.frame` where there are duplicates but you only want the presence or absence of a `1` to be noted, then after these functions you might want to do something like `dat[!(dat %in% c(1,0)] <- 1`.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility not mentioned is the aggregate function. I think this is quite 'readable'.

```
aggregate(cbind(data$X1, data$X2, data$X3, data$X4), 
by = list(category = data$group), FUN = sum)
```